# How to memoize a value based on a property of an object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo

In my functional component, I want to memorize some value which depends on `Id` property of an object:

```
obj={
  innerProperty:{
    id:1
  }
}
useMemo(()=>someComplaxFunction(), [obj.innerProperty.id])
```

I want to do something like this, but the issue is, `innerProperty` can be `undefined`. So I need to add a check for innerProperty, but I cannot add that outside `useMemo` as it gives me error that hooks should not be called conditionally and not even inside as then I will have to add `obj` as dependency which I don't want because other properties may change.

Need to know how can I achieve this.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
obj={
  innerProperty:{
    id:1
  }
}
const id = obj.innerProperty ? obj.innerProperty.id : undefined

// or using optional chaining(?.)
const id = obj.innerProperty?.id

useMemo(()=>someComplaxFunction(id), [id])
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `someComplaxFunction()` check the value of `innerProperty` and return something like `null` so that you memorized value is `null` in this case (or anything else you want). And then use the memorized value in your component assuming that it could potentially be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you shoud do some check. You can't do that logic inside ur dependecies array, but you can do something that way:

```
useMemo(()=> {
    if (obj.innerProperty.id) {
        someComplaxFunction()
    }
}, [obj.innerProperty])
```